# Providing delay between two codes in j2me

Tags: java-me, midlet

I am trying j2me code in which i am putting to thingd a alert message and setCurrentItem()
function..
    display.setCurrent(alert);

```
     display.setCurrentItem(textBox)
```

the problem is that before we can see the alert msg it disappear and because of display.setCurrent(textBox). what should i do to see the alert message correctly and than move to the item which is placed im display.setCurrentItem??

Comment: I tried but its not working Please give me some other suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

I don't really do any High Level GUI coding (meaning Form stuff), so I'm no expert.

But looking at the docs, I can see a `setTimeout(int time)` function on the Alert object.
So my guess is that you should display the TextBox first, and then display the Alert afterwards with a timeout.

```
alert.setTimeout(5000); // 5 seconds
display.setCurrent(textBox);
display.setCurrent(alert);
```

That should display the alert for 5 seconds, and then when dismissed, the textBox should appear.

Looking at the Display object, I also notice another function called `setCurrent(Alert alert, Displayable nextDisplayable)` though, which seems to be even better.
Using that method you should be able to just do

```
Display.setCurrent(alert, textBox);
```

The docs says the following about that method: "Requests that this Alert be made current, and that nextDisplayable be made current after the Alert is dismissed. This call returns immediately regardless of the Alert's timeout value or whether it is a modal alert. The nextDisplayable must not be an Alert, and it must not be null."

Bookmark and use this page a lot:
http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/